# Algorithm to determine whether two numbers in a grid are adjacent

Tags: algorithm, grid

Say I have the following:

```
std::vector<uint> tiles = {
     0, 1, 2, 3,
     4, 5, 6, 7,
     8, 9,10,11,
    12,13,14,15
}
```

Is there an elegant way to determine whether a number is adjacent to another? For example, 0,1,5,8,9 but not 3 would be adjacent to 4. By elegant way I mean without many if statements.

Answer (score 4):

it's easy if you realize that `a/4` is the row of the tile and `a%4` is the column as such:

```
abs(a/4 - b/4)==1 || abs(a%4 - b%4)==1
```

the first part deals with rows and the second with the columns

use `^` to only have either horizontal or vertical and `&&` to use diagonal

Comment: With a = 4 and b = 2, the first part incorrectly evaluates to true.

Comment: yep but this part is correct. it should be && not || and abs(...)<1 for both.

Answer (score 1):

```
row1=a/4;
col1=a%4;
row2=b/4;
col2=b/4;

return abs(row1-row2)<=1 && abs(col1-col2)<=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rowDist = abs(a/4 - b/4);
colDist = abs(a%4 - b%4);

return (rowDist <= 1 && colDist <= 1) && (rowDist + colDist > 0);
```

This prevents the same number being accounted as adjacent.